# Run command script as separate process powershell.exe and pwsh.exe compatible

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

Is there any easy way to invoke a powershell script in separate process while being cross-platform (i.e. supporting both `powershell.exe` and `pwsh.exe`, and ideally powershell on linux (not required)).

If only supporting powershell.exe would be requirement I know I can do

```
$powershellPath = "$env:windir\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
$process = Start-Process $powershellPath -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList ("-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -noninteractive -noprofile " + $scriptBlock) -PassThru
$process.WaitForExit($waitTimeMilliseconds)
```

I could see that I could try to find out if I'm running powershell.exe or pwsh.exe and do some heuristic for the powershell path but it all seems weirdly convoluted... isn't here some better way?

---

A slightly better approach might be to use `$PSHome` variable, e.g.: via

```
 & $PSHOME\powershell.exe -Command '$PID'
```

But even that has the issue of pwsh pshome not containing `powershell.exe` but rather only `pwsh.exe`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `(Get-Process -Id $PID).Path` to determine the executable of your current *PowerShell* and use that to start another process of it:

```
Start-Process (Get-Process -Id $PID).Path
```

It is "cross-platform" and works with PowerShell and PowerShell Core. It even works with PowerShell Core on Linux, as long as you don't call it interactively (calling PowerShell with `Start-Process` seems to break the CLI on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but it works when using it to execute a script file). [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#pid):

> **$PID**
>
> Contains the process identifier (PID) of the process that is hosting the current PowerShell session.

Comment: Nicely done; as for breaking with interactive calls: on Unix-like platforms `-NoNewWindow` is _implied_, because launching the process in a new window, as is the default on Windows, is fundamentally unsupported. Therefore, unless you also use `-Wait`, the newly launched interactive shell will compete for keyboard input with the calling one. [On Unix-like platforms, the utility of `Start-Process`  is very limited](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4521#issuecomment-324931106).

Comment: Beautiful, concise and down to the topic, great answer!